# CSS Quickie on positioning

Tags: html, css, positioning

I would love to know how to make `div` or any element for that matter appear on a new line if it's width is over max of the parent's width.

For example let's say I have one parent div and three child divs, let's say parent's width is `300px` and each child has specified width of `33%` (so each child has width of around 100px), and parent has `display: inline-flex`, now if I add 4th child with width of `33%` I want it to appear on a new line rather than all 4 of the child divs getting resized.

So basically (let's say letter `A` represents each child div) if I add 4th child div I want them to be displayed like this:

`A A A`

`A`

instead of like this:

`A A A A`

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
    height: 100px;
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.child {
    width: 33%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add to parent `flex-wrap`
without that property you will not be able to jump of line.

PD: You are going to have a problem with the children. they will have a margin of 1px that will be very difficult to remove by CSS. I solve it by removing the blanks of the children by HTML

```css
    .parent {
        height: 100px;
        width: 400px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        display: inline-flex;
        /* wrap line */
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        position:relative;
    }
    .child {
       width: 33.3%;
       border: 1px solid black;
       height: 30px;
       box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="child">
            </div><div class="child">
            </div><div class="child">
            </div><div class="child">
            </div><div class="child">
            </div><div class="child">
            </div><div class="child">
            </div><div class="child"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you.

Comment: forget add box-sizing: border-box; and set width 33.3%

Comment: At the moment `flex-wrap: wrap` is all I need :D

Answer (score 1):

Add `flex-wrap:wrap` to parent so that the children can go to next line, if width is not sufficient

```css
.parent {
    height: 100px;
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
    width: 33%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Best practice is to have display:flex to the parent and have flex elements inside. So I suggest

CSS:

```
.parent {
    height: 100px;
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
    flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
    max-width: 33.333333%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```